# May have accidentally turned off all calendar notifications on my Macbook via the command line, which commands might it be?

Tags: macos, calendar

I am on Ventura and have a Macbook Pro. I vaguely recall about a year ago I might have used a command via the terminal to manually turn off all calendar notifications.

Even though I have turned on all settings I can find in System Preferences and Calendar Preferences for alerts, it is still not showing any calendar event alerts such as banners. I am wondering if there might be commands I can check in terminal to see if I manually shut down all calendar events on the backend. Thanks.